# How to force formatStyle() in DataTable/shiny to output formatting based on other variable?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Say I have a following `datatable` object, that uses conditional formatting for `mpg` column:

```
DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(mtcars,
      options = list(
        searching = FALSE,
        pageLength = nrow(mtcars),
        dom = 't'
      ),
      rownames = FALSE,
      selection = 'none') %>%
      formatStyle('mpg',
                  background = styleColorBar(mtcars$mpg, 'lightblue'),
                  backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                  backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                  backgroundPosition = 'center'))
```

[image]

Is it possible to define conditional formatting for `mpg` column, but where sizes of conditional formatting histogram bars are based on other variable (e.g. `disp`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
datatable(mtcars,
          options = list(
            searching = FALSE,
            pageLength = nrow(mtcars),
            dom = 't'
          ),
          rownames = FALSE,
          selection = 'none') %>%
  formatStyle('mpg','disp',
              background = styleColorBar(mtcars$disp, 'lightblue'),
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html for more information.

[image: 'mpg' format depending on 'disp']

Comment: Thanks for the answer and hint, but it does not work correctly... It returns "100% covered" bars. Have you tested it - what was the outcome?

Comment: Just added a screenshot of my outcome, mpg depends on disp for the style, you got a different format?

Comment: (+1) Yes, I did get different result ( http://pasteboard.co/1Jxc5R4w.png )... that *is* strange. Thanks for help, I'll have to research this topic. Are you using recent shiny on Windows?

Comment: Im using ubuntu 14.04.3 with R version 3.2.2, shiny_0.12.2 and DT_0.1.34. Maybe try installing the dev version of DT, devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT').

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it also on linux machine. Unfortunatelly, I have to stick to non-dev version of DT in my project so will have to test it on cran version. UPDATE: on linux the same bug appears. So it seems to be a DT bug.

Comment: Just tested it with DT_0.1 and it shows me the 100% covered bars, after updating to DT_0.1.39 it works as above. Sorry you might have to wait for an update or search for a jquery solution instead :(

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a bug. I'll wait for other potential answer that gives some workaround and if I won't get any I'll accept yours.